# Spring Boot H2 database doesn't self-reset. Can't find existing data. Problems with liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, h2, liquibase, jdbctemplate

I have the following set-up:

1. Spring Boot
2. Embedded H2 Database
3. Liquibase scrips to create data

First of all, I want to start from a clean slate every time I restart my application.
I want liquibase to re-create the H2 tables from the scripts every time. Right now it doesn't and just keeps existing data. If I delete the data manually from the h2 console, it doesn't recreate them unless I update changeSet id-s.

Even then, right now, I have an existing table called User which contains data. I can see it from my h2 console. But suddenly, when I use my JdbcTemplate query, it doesn't find any results and I can't login anymore (it's gets a null result).

**EDIT:**

I fixed the data query by adding setters as well to my User.java object. That fixed it (I hoped I could do without them, but appears not).

But I still wish that the tables created my liquibase would reset each time so I can change the queries without it giving me errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way to get a fresh db on every startup is using an in-memory database instead of a file.

Just replace
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/company;MV_STORE=false`
by
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:company;MV_STORE=false`
in your application.properties

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something because I thought it was supposed to be nonpersistent by default. 

The following doesn't really have anything to do with the question anymore, but I was wondering - is this kind of a basic setup okay? The login and authentication part? I haven't really done it this way before.